# Division by 10 for large values of n in python gives inaccurate answers

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was doing a simple problem of solving the sum of digits of 2^1000. The solution is pretty trivial, I know; but look at this code snippet:

```
n=2**1000
sum=0
while n>0:
    sum+=n%10
    n=int(n/10)
    print(n)
print(sum)
```

The above snippet gives the wrong answer. However, if I make a minor change:

```
n=2**1000
sum=0
while n>0:
    sum+=n%10
    n//=10     # changed
    print(n)
print(sum)
```

then the answer is correct. Can someone tell me what the difference is here?

(NOTE: This difference is only seen for large values of `n`.)

Comment: what makes you think you can store `2**1000` in a 64bit-int system?  you force python to destroy 936 of those 1000 bits when you typecast to int. the second one works, because 2**1000 becomes a float, and then stays a float.

Comment: @MarcB `2**1000` is a perfectly valid expression, and will return the correct answer, try it...

Comment: @MarcB I didnt knew it could but FYI it can and I checked the type in both  the codes,they both are 'int'.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like you're using python3, the `//` operator performs integer division, and the `/` operator does floating point division, which on huge values loses precision.

For example:

```
>>> int((2**1000 / 49) * 49) == 2**1000
False
```